# When using Immersive Mode with dialogs, nav. bar reappears and resizes my layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

I'm using Immersive Mode in my app when it's running on Android 4.4+. (http://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html)

My activity indeed shows in full screen, and I work around the volume key pressing by using `setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener`. I also have similar code for putting dialogs into immersive mode.

However, when a dialog is shown, the nav. bars jump on the screen and then retreat immediately. When the dialog is dismissed it's even worse - the nav. bars jump and resize the activity behind.

The following is my class for supporting immersive mode. It is simply called on each Activity's onResume and also a separate function is called when building each dialog.

Did I miss any flag or callback, or is it a known Android issue?

```
public class ImmersiveModeHelper {

    public ImmersiveModeHelper(Activity activity)
    {
        mActivity = activity;
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void supportFullScreenImmersiveMode()
    {
        MyLog.d("ImmersiveModeHelper: supportFullScreenImmersiveMode: ");

        // Support full-screen immersive mode on Android 4.4 and up
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19)
        {
            // Get the needed flags by reflection and use them
            try
            {
                final int immersiveFlag = View.class.getField("SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY")
                        .getInt(null);
                final int hideNavigationFlag = View.class
                        .getField("SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION").getInt(null);
                final int fullScreenFlag = View.class.getField("SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN").getInt(
                        null);


                // Set the flags to the window decor view
                mActivity.getWindow().getDecorView()
                        .setSystemUiVisibility(immersiveFlag | hideNavigationFlag | fullScreenFlag);

                // Set a callback to be called when visibility changes
                // (workaround
                // for volume keys)
                mActivity
                        .getWindow()
                        .getDecorView()
                        .setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(
                                new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener()
                                {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility)
                                    {
                                        MyLog.d("ImmersiveModeHelper.supportFullScreenImmersiveMode().new OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {...}: onSystemUiVisibilityChange: " +
                                                "");

                                        if ((visibility & (immersiveFlag | hideNavigationFlag)) == 0)
                                        {
                                            Handler uiHandler = UiThreadUtils.getUiHandler();
                                            uiHandler.removeCallbacks(mHideSystemUiCallback);
                                            uiHandler.postDelayed(mHideSystemUiCallback,
                                                    HIDE_SYSTEM_UI_DELAY_MILLI);
                                        }
                                    }
                                });

            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                MyLog.e("ImmersiveModeHelper: supportFullScreenImmersiveMode: couldn't support immersive mode by reflection");
            }
        } else
        {
            MyLog.i("ImmersiveModeHelper: supportFullScreenImmersiveMode: not supported on this platform version");
        }
    }

    public static void supportFullScreenImmersiveModeForDialog(final Dialog dlg)
    {
        MyLog.d("ImmersiveModeHelper: supportFullScreenImmersiveModeForDialog: ");

        // Support full-screen immersive mode on Android 4.4 and up
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19)
        {
            final Window dlgWindow = dlg.getWindow();

            // Get the needed flags by reflection and use them
            try
            {
                final int immersiveFlag = View.class.getField("SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY")
                        .getInt(null);
                final int hideNavigationFlag = View.class
                        .getField("SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION").getInt(null);
                final int fullScreenFlag = View.class.getField("SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN").getInt(
                        null);


                // Set the flags to the window decor view
                int flags = dlgWindow.getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility();
                flags |= (immersiveFlag | hideNavigationFlag | fullScreenFlag);
                dlgWindow.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(flags);

                // Set a callback to be called when visibility changes
                // (workaround for volume keys)
                dlgWindow.getDecorView().setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(
                        new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility)
                            {
                                MyLog.d("ImmersiveModeHelper.supportFullScreenImmersiveModeForDialog(...).new OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {...}: onSystemUiVisibilityChange: ");
                                if ((visibility & (immersiveFlag | hideNavigationFlag)) == 0)
                                {
                                    Runnable hideSystemUiCallback = new Runnable()
                                    {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run()
                                        {
                                            supportFullScreenImmersiveModeForDialog(dlg);
                                        }
                                    };

                                    Handler uiHandler = UiThreadUtils.getUiHandler();
                                    uiHandler.removeCallbacks(hideSystemUiCallback);
                                    uiHandler.postDelayed(hideSystemUiCallback,
                                            HIDE_SYSTEM_UI_DELAY_MILLI);
                                }
                            }
                        });

            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                MyLog.e("ImmersiveModeHelper: supportFullScreenImmersiveMode: couldn't support immersive mode by reflection");
            }
        } else
        {
            MyLog.i("ImmersiveModeHelper: supportFullScreenImmersiveMode: not supported on this platform version");
        }
    }

    private Activity mActivity;

    private Runnable mHideSystemUiCallback = new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            supportFullScreenImmersiveMode();
        }
    };

    private static final int HIDE_SYSTEM_UI_DELAY_MILLI = 0;

}
```

Comment: Hi @SirKnigget, did you found any solution to this? I'm stuck into this problem as well.

Comment: @Ruzanna No, I didn't find a solution

Answer (score 4):

From the Google API:
It's good practice to include other system UI flags (such as SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION and SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE) to keep the content from resizing when the system bars hide and show.

You should also make sure that the action bar and other UI controls are hidden at the same time. This snippet demonstrates how to hide and show the status and navigation bars, without resizing the content:

```
// This snippet hides the system bars.
private void hideSystemUI() {
    // Set the IMMERSIVE flag.
    // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the content
    // doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
    mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
}

// This snippet shows the system bars. It does this by removing all the flags
// except for the ones that make the content appear under the system bars.
private void showSystemUI() {
    mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It helps makes the nav. bar less annoying, but I don't want it to appear at all. It jumps on the screen each time I show a message dialog (even when the dialog itself is set as immersive).

Comment: I opened a similar question with a bounty here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22794049/how-to-maintain-the-immersive-mode-in-dialogs with no replies, probably a solution doesn't exist.

Comment: It's a known issue with Dialogs and Immersive (Sticky) Mode, see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=68031

Answer (score 1):

In Dialog or BottomSheetDialogFragment you have to implement this solution which is work for me.

Step 1:

In your dialog or BottomSheetDialog, write this code in onActivityCreated method,

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    var viewParent = view
    while (viewParent is View) {
        viewParent.fitsSystemWindows = false
        viewParent.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener { _, insets -> insets }
        viewParent = viewParent.parent as View?
    }
}
```

Step 2: 
Also, override the below method :

```
  override fun setupDialog(dialog: Dialog, style: Int) {
    super.setupDialog(dialog, style)
    dialog?.window?.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE)

}
```

Now see the magic :)

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was adding the following to the parent layout xml:

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by setting my flags on `onWindowFocusChanged()` rather than `onResume()` as per https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.
The problem is the full screen popup resets the SYSTEM_UI flags. Tested and works.

```
    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        // Before setting full screen flags, we must wait a bit to let UI settle; otherwise, we may
        // be trying to set app to immersive mode before it's ready and the flags do not stick

        long IMMERSIVE_FLAG_TIMEOUT = 500L;
        int FLAGS_FULLSCREEN = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE |
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE |
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY |
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);

        mFullView.postDelayed(() -> mFrameLayout.setSystemUiVisibility(FLAGS_FULLSCREEN),
                IMMERSIVE_FLAG_TIMEOUT);
    }
```

I think you can also follow the new guidelines in https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive. I have not tested it though.

```
private fun hideSystemBars() {
  val windowInsetsController =
      ViewCompat.getWindowInsetsController(window.decorView) ?: return
  // Configure the behavior of the hidden system bars
  windowInsetsController.systemBarsBehavior =
      WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
  // Hide both the status bar and the navigation bar
  windowInsetsController.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
}
```